# Plesk and Security -- hidden accounts?

Tags: security, plesk

My sys-admin claims that he has a "special password" with which to log into my website's Plesk account.  From the user's tab, it says there is only one user (an admin), and it is the one we both log into.  He claims that this isn't the only account, and if I were to change the password on him he would be able to go in and change it on me and I would no longer be able to access it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not a hidden account. It's possible if application was installed by plesk user and this user used as user for web site application.

How it can be solved:

- Your sysadmin can create in Plesk separate user for you which can access to your web application(there is bug in Plesk before 11.5 that Plesk creates users with name like smth@domain.com and such user names can't be accepted by application, but there is no such bug in 11.5).
- your sysadmin can(if he is a reseller or plesk's admin) create some plesk user like customer and move domain with application to this customer and than try first option.
- You can changes password inside application, not in plesk. This operation not affects Plesk's user, because plesk don't know what happens inside of application.